# Loading WMS Layer with MapWinGIS from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, c#, mapwingis

I'm working on a C# project using MapWinGIS 4.9 and Geoserver 2.13 Previously I've stored Shapefiles in Geoserver and I want to load in a C# project using MapWinGIS control.

I'm using [WmsLayer Class Reference](https://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/class_wms_layer.html) but still had no idea how should I call the GetMap request from geoserver.

Also I've been searching for documentation but had no success.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: According to the documentation ~ https://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/class_wms_layer.html#aeee6a505240ad688c70c03c742b26a33 you don't need to construct the GetMap request, just set the baseURL

Comment: It's not clear to me the way to create a WmsLayer and then add to the AxMap control. Also the reference points to the function AddLayer() but had no success.

Comment: Property TransparentColor is type of UInt so in case of using white color as transparent it should be something like (VB.NET): Dim c As Color = Color.White Dim b() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(c.ToArgb) wmsLayer.TransparentColor = BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 0) (C#.NET): Color c = Color.White; wmsLayer.TransparentColor = (uint)(((c.A << 24) | (c.R << 16) | (c.G << 8) | c.B);

Answer (score 2):

It was not so complicated, here is an example:

```
//We need a control map, a wmsLayer and a layerHandle.
AxMap axMap = new AxMap();
int layerHandle = -1;
WmsLayer wmsLayer = new WmsLayer();
Extents extents = new Extents();

//Set the wmsLayer properties, taken from geoserver.
extents.SetBounds(-180, -90, 0, 0, 90, 0);
wmsLayer.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/seceot_test/wms";
wmsLayer.BoundingBox = extents;
wmsLayer.Contrast = (float)1.0;
wmsLayer.DoCaching = false;
wmsLayer.Epsg = 4326;
wmsLayer.Format = @"image%2Fpng";
wmsLayer.Gamma = (float)1.0;
wmsLayer.Layers = "dev_test:infrastructure_100k";
wmsLayer.Name = "Infrastructure 100k";
wmsLayer.Opacity = 255;
wmsLayer.UseCache = false;
wmsLayer.Id = 1;
wmsLayer.UseTransparentColor = false;
wmsLayer.Key = "1";
wmsLayer.Version = tkWmsVersion.wvAuto;
wmsLayer.TransparentColor = 255;
wmsLayer.UseTransparentColor = true;

// If everything is correct, AddLayer() does the job.
layerHandle = axMap.AddLayer(wmsLayer, true);

// Testing purposes, should print "Layers added to the map: 1"
Console.WriteLine("Layers added to the map: {0}", this.axMap.NumLayers);
```

And that's all!